# Has ES File Explorer removed the adware?

Tags: es-file-explorer

I used ES File Explorer for a long time, but when they made the terrible decision to add that "Charging Boost" adware tagalong I had to uninstall, probably along with 2/3 of the apps users.

Is it now safe to re-install ES now? Have they removed all the internal adware from the app?

Comment: Please see this new article 2017/02/10 [10 most useless apps and games for Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/most-useless-apps-android-749163). Most prominent, but specifically named in the list: ES File Explorer (along with quote-Booster apps, Anti-Virus apps, and Task Killers-unquote)

Comment: They have an option to shut off the charging boost. The ads aren't worse than any other free app.

Answer (score 1):

## Nope.

ES Global will none removing all their Adware/Ads/Charging Boost/Complete bulls**t they added. Its an example of a good app falling to greedy devs.

Here's some complaints: [Soooo, One from slashdot)](https://tech.slashdot.org/story/16/05/10/1816225/latest-update-to-es-file-explorer-android-app-brings-adware-to-your-lockscreen) Ummm, [One from the Android Police on ES Pro](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/11/28/after-adding-a-bunch-of-bloat-to-the-free-app-es-file-explorers-3-pro-version-will-take-some-of-it-it-away/) And XDA has a [Nice list on everything wrong with the New ES, and a story too!](https://www.xda-developers.com/es-file-explorer-a-short-story-of-a-fallen-king/) Read that to the kids.

Comment: Damn! And that was a good app.

Comment: I know, I used it for years. When it started hitting the fan, I rolled back and modded the package name so it won't update :)